# wget consistently fails on MacOS Big Sur (macports install of wget) but works on Linux

Tags: html, wget, macos-big-sur, macports

I have installed wget on a Mac with Big Sur using MacPorts. The version of wget is:

```
GNU Wget 1.21.2 built on darwin20.6.0.
```

I cannot get wget to download files from a server. It only downloads what appear to be HTML files. The command I use, as recommended by the site, is:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge "https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/products/ionex/2021/142/c2pg1420.21i.Z"
```

This downloads a file called "c2pg1420.21i.Z". What's downloaded is an HTML file that starts with
`<!DOCTYPE html>`. It's not the file I expected. This command always downloads an html file, no matter what file I ask for.

The exact same command on a Linux box works. The version of wget is older:

```
iars{mannucci}43: wget -V
GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.
```

I have looked at a number of web sites and none of the fixes I see works for me.

Comment: I just tried it.  I get the HTML page asking for a login.  I think it's the same page if you navigate to that url with your browser.

Comment: Also take a look at the log messages: Connecting to cddis.nasa.gov (cddis.nasa.gov)|198.118.199.52|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found <== REDIRECT

Answer (score 0):

earthdata.nasa.gov has download instructions at https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/CDDIS_Archive_Access.html. The instructions explain that you need to provide username and password in a .netrc file.  The format is `machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login <username> password <password>` where username and password are your current username for the Earthdata website.  Create this file in your home directory with read access for just yourself.

Make sure to delete any previous output files and rerun your wget command.

I suspect that your Linux system has a .netrc file with valid credentials.